# Need file details in one line by using multiple commands in Ansible

Tags: ansible, find, centos7, aix, ls

I'm on AiX 6.1 system.

I need the "file permissions" "file owner" "date in dd-mm-yyyy format" "absolute file path" "cksum value" all separated by a single white-space.

I'm using the "find" & "cksum" commands for this purpose with ansible shell module.

The reason I prefer "find" over "ls" command is that the "ls" command will change the time column format depending on the age of the file eg: as shown below:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 89 Aug 29 12:08 booking
-rw-r--r--  1 root bin   0 Oct 21  2016 basic.log
```

Below command works and gives me the desired output on a Redhat Linux CentOs 7

```
find test.sh -printf "%M %u %TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %h/%f $(cksum<test.sh | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

Output:

```
-rwxrwxr-x root 2019-08-29 17:25 ./test.sh 3522761671
```

Below is the working ansible command on CentOS 7 for the same:

```
ansible localhost -m shell -a "find test.sh -printf \"%M %u %TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %h/%f $(cksum<test.sh | cut -d' ' -f1)\n\""
```

Output:

```
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
-rwxrwxr-x root 2019-08-29 17:25 ./test.sh 3522761671
```

The problem is that this solution does not work on AiX 6.1 system and I get this error:

```
find: bad option -printf
```

Can someone please help suggest a solution for Ansible command for AiX that works exactly like the CentOS command shared above?

Answer (score 1):

Module [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) does not implement the full functionality of the *find* command. Use [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html) module to get the details. For example the play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: /scratch/test1
        patterns: test.sh
        recurse: true
      register: results
    - set_fact:
        list_of_files: "{{ results.files|json_query('[].path') }}"
    - debug:
        var: list_of_files
    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        get_checksum: true
      loop: "{{ list_of_files }}"
      register: results
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.item }}
              {{ item.stat.mode }}
              {{ item.stat.pw_name }}
              {{ item.stat.mtime }}
              {{ item.stat.checksum }}"
      loop: "{{ results.results }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```
"list_of_files": [
    "/scratch/test1/bin/test.sh", 
    "/scratch/test1/sbin/test.sh"
]

"msg": "/scratch/test1/bin/test.sh 0664 admin 1569127708.13 d7b5ad41fb2c3..."
"msg": "/scratch/test1/sbin/test.sh 0664 admin 1569127711.13 fe20d6a0d3c2e..."
```

---

Notes

- By default the module *find* returns a list
- By default the checksum algorithm is sha1
- Use *stat.atime* if "access time" is needed
- Use *stat.ctime* if "creation time" is needed
- To convert the date take a look at [ansible manipulate file with a date format](https://serverfault.com/questions/728662/ansible-manipulate-file-with-a-date-format), or write a plugin.

---

With the plugin below

```
$ cat filter_plugins/datetime_filters.py
from datetime import date, datetime

def datetime_epoch_strftime(epoch, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(float(epoch)).strftime(format)

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters. Interface to Python datetime methods.

        datetime Basic date and time types
        https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html'''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'datetime_epoch_strftime': datetime_epoch_strftime
        }
```

the modified debug item

```
{{ item.stat.mtime|datetime_epoch_strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}
```

gives

```
"msg": "/scratch/test1/bin/test.sh 0664 admin 22-09-2019 20d6a0d ..."
"msg": "/scratch/test1/sbin/test.sh 0664 admin 22-09-2019 fe20d6a ..."
```

This plugin and others are available at [GitHub](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Can I get the output of cksum which is a 10 digit number instead of what checksum gives me here as they both are different. Also, I was looking for some AiX command recommendations to get similar output instead of changing the ansible module from shell to stat.

Comment: Module *stat* does not provide *cksum* algorithm.

Comment: @Ashar it sounds like you're trying to match this Ansible output with some pre-existing output.  Rather than making the Ansible playbook overly complex to bring in the "cksum" output, I'd suggest using the native checksum instead as it will be more consistently unique instead of the native "cyclic redundancy check" that chksum produces. (Older CRC values are highly prone to collisions and could lead to false positives with two different files having the same CRC value.)

Comment: Thank you for the input guys !!